# Xcode: Failed to load profile. Profile is missing the required UUID property

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to download provision profiles, but I constantly get this error.

[image]

[image]

Profiles are managed automatically, UUID for device is on the list of all UUID on developer portal.

The same profile works well on another machine.

How can I fix it?

Comment: did you activate you apple account, if yes when ?

Comment: @Tobi I activated my apple account I think on 2013, I was added to the current team in March this year. Last month everything was smooth with this account, it's something new.

Comment: its probably an agent problem check with him if he might need to accept a new policies or something usually sent on email, if not, try to clean build and hope for the best ...

Comment: add device udid you are using

Comment: @DevilDecoder it's already in the list

Comment: @Tobi checking agent profile, thanks for idea. I'll report the result as soon as get an access

Comment: good luck, hope it works usually this process takes up to 24 hours

Comment: @Tobi heh, this doesn't help! :) btw, I tried to do it on another Mac and everything is fine. It seems there is some internal issue that could take up to 24 hours =)

Comment: It was a suggestion heh

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: @vladiulianbogdan I has resolved issue by installing the new Xcode 10

Comment: Updating the OS from 10.13.3 to 10.13.6 fixed it for me.

Comment: I had similar issue. Got it fixed by taking profiles from system on which it is working (Path: ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/). Now install those profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by installing the new Xcode 10. 
By the way, when I removed all caches for my previously installed Xcode 9.2 there was still the issue.

Absolutely issue is related to the Xcode.

Comment: Note that 10.13.6 is required to install Xcode 10.1

Answer (score 10):

If updating OS version and xcode version did not help, please check the contents of provision files before opening them with xcode.

In our case it was Outlook clearing the contents of the provision files. Outlook might clear contents of files if you choose the "Download All Files" option within the email. I guess it scans files while compressing them into a single .rar file. Downloading one by one does is fine.

Comment: it helped me. Thanks a lot. Never thought it could be the issue

Comment: Never expected this could be issue. Thanks!! +1 for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading from macOS 10.13.2 to 10.13.6 fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -3):

Please Follow below steps:

1- Need to **unplug** your device from your computer OR choose `Generic iOS Device` from the top in **xCode**

2- uncheck/check **Automatically manage signing** it will creating and updating profiles, and certificates.

3- Clean `(command+shift+k)`

Comment: It doesn't help

Comment: This didn't helped.